# Can't add PHP to my VF page

Tags: visualforce, php

I'm trying to add some simple php to a VF page and I'm getting this error:

```
The processing instruction must begin with the name of the target
```

Could someone point out where the problem is?

```
    <div id="content">

        <div contenteditable="true" id="inputr"></div>

        <?php
            echo "My first PHP script!";
        ?>

        <img id="thisImg"></img>

        <div id="btn"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? What does it do? Maybe there's an out-of-the-box solution in Visualforce and Apex that you can borrow. ;-)

Comment: Well what I want to do is scrap some html from a webpage, PHP seems to be the handiest way to accomplish this. Not with VF however it would seem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualforce pages don't support PHP. PHP is a server-side language. You must use Visualforce tags, Javascript, or Apex controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel, is there perhaps some convention for 'converting' PHP to Apex for VisualForce?

Comment: Not really. Take a look at the documentation and post a question here when you run into issues.